# PHP/HTML form in Wordpress with MySQL query

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to retrieve a list of Wordpress user groups I've set up using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/groups/), and to give the user the ability to email each group individually using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/email-users/). This basically reproduces a listserv.

After installing both plugins and setting up the list of groups the email plugin was showing the Wordpress roles i.e editor/subscriber etc, not my custom groups. So, I've opened up the form that sends the group emails, here's [the original trunk](http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/rotarywebproject/trunk/wp-content/plugins/email-users-rwp/email_users_group_mail_form.php).

Now after hacking away from line 97 to line 119 I've ended up with this:

```
<select id="send_roles" name="send_roles[]" multiple="multiple"
        size="8" style="width: 654px; height: 250px;">
            <?php
                $roles = mailusers_get_roles($user_ID, MAILUSERS_ACCEPT_MASS_EMAIL_USER_META);
                foreach ($roles as $key => $value) {
            ?>


<?php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_groups_group") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php
                    echo (in_array($key, $send_roles) ? ' selected="yes"' : '');?>>
                    <?php
                        printf('%s - %s', __('Group', MAILUSERS_I18N_DOMAIN), $info['name']);
 } 
 ?>
        </option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
</select>
```

This is great, it shows the email form. Now with my list of user groups the only problem is that no matter which email group I select it always sends the email to all the users in all the groups. After submitting the form the groups show up as all being selected instead of just the group I've chosen.

If anyone can help I'd be much appreciated!

I'm on Wordpress 3.5.

Comment: Why have i been voted down please at least give me a reason, so as to better my question next time:(

Comment: Thank you for the styling! Halfer. I'm glad this isn't dead yet.

Comment: Don't worry about the odd downvote. It may have been because the question could have been made a bit clearer with hyperlinks and paragraphing, so I've improved it for you.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise I needed to be quite that precise and clean when posting the questions i'll take little more care next time. :D
I'm awful when it comes to PHP I hope some on can give me a little insight I've got a funny feeling it might have something to do with the submit button. but god knows!!!

Comment: I presume this is a `post` form. With that in mind, find the code that handles the form submission, and put in `print_r($_POST); exit();` in it, prior to any email sending etc. This is a handy debugging technique to check if what you have entered into the form is the same as what is submitted. If that's all good, then trace the code to see how it is being interpreted. Did you write the submission handler, or is this done by one of the plugins you mention?

Comment: (Yes, quite a few readers here - myself probably included - are a bit OCD when it comes to how questions are presented and formatted. It's a longstanding hackish trait, and unlikely to change any time soon imo `;)`).

Comment: your right @halfer I didn't write the submission handler, thanks for the elbow in the right direction, Your right this is a post form, I've added the print_r and this is the output:
    `Array ( [send] => true [fromName] => admin [fromAddress] =>         XXXXXXXX@gmail.com [mail_format] => html [send_roles] => Array ( [0] => subscriber ) [subject] => test [mailcontent] => test test     tes [Submit] => Send Email » )`
 so from the look's of it it's stil picking up the subcribers role instead of my new input...

Comment: Ah right. Have a scan around the whole of the page to see where that is coming from. If you have two controls of the same name (e.g. yours and one from WP maybe?) then only one will be sent. You'll need to remove the controls you _don't_ want for yours to work.

Comment: Hello @halfer or anybody that may be out there!!
right i've scanned through the page and i'm assuming it's line 28 and 29 that's causing the issue but even after removing it, it still sends to all my user, i've tried replacing the send_role both with $data and $info but to no avail. 
I'm posting it to [codepad](http://codepad.org/vHC9bkgA) if you have a chance to take a look at it that would be great! I'll still be hacking away at it to see if I can get it to yield anyhow.
Kind regards 
Chris

Comment: ^ Link broken above. Codepad isn't suitable, as it will try to run your code (see at the end) - use pastie.org or similar in future. Look at the help feature when writing a comment to see how to create links.

Comment: So, to summarise the problem for readers: (1) are your form controls named correctly? (2) have you removed any previous form controls that would confuse output? (3) is the dumped contents of `$_POST` correct when the form is submitted?

Comment: @halfer
[pastie](http://pastie.org/5655778)

my form controls seem to be named correctly from what I can see,
more than remove them I adapted them with my current code( possibly causing this issue) and no no matter what I change the dumped content of `$_POST` appears the same `[send_roles] => Array ( [0] => subscriber )`
Thank you for your patience and excuse my complete noobness when it comes both to Stackoverflow and PHP.
Chris
Note*(it's telling me not to have a discussion in the comments and to use the chat)

Comment: OK, so since the answer to (3) is "no", then either (1) or (2) would be likely to be a "no" as well. Do a view source in the browser to see all controls on the page, and to double-check their contents and naming. That all said, it is possible that something is modifying `$_POST` - it's bad practice, but it is possible.

Comment: A pastie of the resulting HTML page may be more useful here, I wonder?

Comment: [Pastie of the html](http://pastie.org/5656274) before submitting the form and [pastie of the html](http://pastie.org/5656289) after submitting form @halfer
thank you again for the dilligence!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stripped-down (non-Wordpress) HTML demo to help reveal the problem with your code:

```
<html>
<body>

    <?php if ($_POST): ?>
        <?php print_r($_POST); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <form method="post">

        <select id="send_roles"
                name="send_roles[]"
                multiple="multiple"
                size="8"
                style="width: 654px; height: 250px;"
        >
            <option value="registered">Group - Registered</option>
            <option value="mens">Group - Mens group</option>
            <option value="monday">Group - Monday night</option>
            <option value="tueday">Group - Tuesday Night</option>
            <option value="unaffiliated">Group - Unaffiliated</option>
            <option value="alumni">Group - Alumni</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You have two problems (both fixed in the example):

- Your option values are all the same, these need to be different
- Each option value is not closed, except for the last one

So, it looks like the values coming from `mailusers_get_roles()` are at fault - don't make each of them "subscriber". Also, move the `</option>` to before the preceding brace, opening/closing PHP tags as necessary to do so.

Comment: Ok I get it! 
Thank you for all the help @halfer: 
now it's outputting the option values correctly: 
 `<option value="Registered">Group - Registered</option>
  <option value="Mens group">Group - Mens group</option> 
  <option value="Monday night">Group - Monday night</option> 
  <option value="Tuesday Night">Group - Tuesday Night</option> 
  <option value="Unaffiliated">Group - Unaffiliated</option> 
  <option value="Alumni">Group - Alumni</option> `
but now it's telling me there are no recipients found, I Will win with this though.

Comment: No worries. I suggest you avoid spaces in option names, and use lower-case tokens as per my example. Your way will work, but these values should be considered "fixed" and thus won't change if you were to, for example, translate the labels into a different spoken language.

Comment: (Aside: you probably want to change the spelling of "Mens group" to "Men's group", since the apostrophe is necessary to denote possession. Another good reason to use lower-case tokens, since apostrophes cannot be used in values.)

Comment: thank you I'll change them now, I was trying to advoid having to use trailing slashes hence the lack of an apostrophe. I planned on getting it to work first... 
Not to beat the same drum but do you have any pointer on where i should be looking for "no recipients found fix"?

Comment: Not really, I suspect that is very specific to your use case. Do a search across the whole site (WP core and plugins included) to see what is raising that error. Is that the code part of your submit handler?

Comment: yes it's the code part of my submit handler that and sods law!
LOL umm I'm searching through the core now.
Thanks again for all the patience @halfer